# trying to add two css files in my MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to include two css files for my MVC project. One for admin side and other for client side. For admin I have used shared/_Layout.cshtml file where I have added the following line of code...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For client side, I am trying to use Site.Master file in the Store folder, which is not in the Shared folder, where I haved added the following line of code between head...

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"> 
  <link href="~/Content/Style.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In my Views folder called Store/index.cshtml I have included the following line of code...

```
@{
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Style.css")" rel="stylesheet"    
  type="text/css" />
 }
```

but this is giving me a warning message...
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'link' cannot be nested within element 'link'.

So my 1st question is it possible to use two css file for my MVC project?
2nd, Have I approached this the correct way? 
3rd question, what shall I do about this warning message.

In for my client side I am trying to create a sidebar in the Site.Master file adding the following line of code... But nothing is happening?

```
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"> 
    <link href="~/Content/Style.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<!-- adding the following line of code -->
 <div id="header">
  <div class="title">My Project</div>
</div>
<div id="categories">
  Will put something useful here later
</div>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <div class="title">SPORTS STORE</div>  
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

I am using VS 2010, ASP.NET MVC 3 in C#. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to use two css file for my MVC project?**

Definitely

**Have I approached this the correct way?**

You're not using the proper syntax within the `<link>` tag to resolve the url to your CSS file. Try using this:

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Content/Style.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**What shall I do about this warning message?**

Might be a typo, but you also have a 2 closing double quotes "". This warning message should go away if you remove this.

Comment: I am afraid the code you have provided does not work... I had to changed to...<link href="@ResolveUrl("~/")> Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. Error msg: The name 'ResolveUrl' does not exist in the current context. Pls can you have a look at it again

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way. Added a new layout.cshtml file in Views/Shared path. When creating a new index.cshtml through controller, you can select the new layout.cshtml file in Razor. in MVC 3 you don't need to define Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutClient.cshtml"; in each view file. _ViewStart.cstml has been already been created for you. So you can avoid the DRY.